# Cannot get value from Radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this code:

```
currentquestion = 0
currentcheckbox = 1
which_radio_var = StringVar(inside_test_root)

while currentquestion < len(questions):
                    print('currentcheckbox', currentcheckbox)
                    Radiobutton(inside_test_root, text=questions[currentquestion], value=currentcheckbox, variable=which_radio_var, indicatoron=0, wraplength=30).grid(row=currentquestion+1, column=0)
                    currentquestion += 2
                    currentcheckbox += 1
```

`x = which_radio_var.get()`

I get the Radiobuttons coming up fine and everything works properly, apart from wen I try to test these radiobuttons with the code:

```
Button(inside_test_root, text='oof', command=print(x)).grid(column = 77, row = 77)
```

Nothing prints. Is it something to do with the nature i made the radiobuttons? I need a way to not know the amount of buttons that are being produced beforehand.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: where are you setting `x` that you are printing?

Comment: ah, sorry, will add that bit now

Comment: `command=print(x)` means to print `x` *right now*, and use the return value of the `print()` function (which is None) as the command to execute when the button is clicked.  `command=lambda: print(which_radio_var.get())` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is as jasonharper said, I missed out the lambda, meaning that i was calling the print function the first time and never again

"command=print(x) means to print x right now, and use the return value of the print() function (which is None) as the command to execute when the button is clicked. command=lambda: print(which_radio_var.get()) would do the job. "

Updated code is now: (the variable 'x' has become 'radio' to fit with the rest of my program)

```
                if questiontype == 'Multiple Choice':
                    currentquestion = 0
                    currentcheckbox = 1
                    which_radio_var = StringVar(inside_test_root)
                    print (which_radio_var)
                    while currentquestion < len(questions):
                        print('currentcheckbox', currentcheckbox)
                        Radiobutton(inside_test_root, text=questions[currentquestion], value=currentcheckbox, variable=which_radio_var, indicatoron=0, wraplength=30).grid(row=currentquestion+1, column=0)
                        currentquestion += 2
                        currentcheckbox += 1
                        print(which_radio_var.get())
                    radio = which_radio_var.get()
                    Button(inside_test_root, text='oof', command=lambda: print(radio)).grid(column = 77, row = 77)
```